# Why is my network connections greyed?

Tags: wireless, network-manager

My network connections are working and I can see existing connections in connection manager, but just recently my top RHS desktop menus all seemed greyed.

So if I am connected to wifi, I no longer get a list of available networks anymore. How do I get back to that stage?

[image: screenshot showing network connections menu]

Comment: You probably set the connection somewhere else, like `/etc/network/interfaces` or `wicd`.

Comment: If you want to enable this feature you showed, you must install or enable NetworkManager. `sudo apt install networkmanager`, so you edit `/etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf` and set `managed=true`